# Aligning a Bootstrap 4 button group to the bottom of a flexbox div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have some HTML like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="border d-flex align-items-baseline m-2 p-2" style="width: 400px">
  <div class="btn-group mr-2">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group flex-grow-1">
    <label for="volume">Volume:</label>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="volume" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="7">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the Prev and Next buttons are aligned to the top of the div, like this:

[image]

My goal was to have them aligned to the bottom, like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that? I thought that's what the `align-items-baseline` class would do, but I must be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align-items-baseline` class do `align-items: baseline`, not 
but you need `align-items: flex-end`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="align-items: flex-end" class="border d-flex m-2 p-2" style="width: 400px">
  <div class="btn-group mr-2">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group flex-grow-1">
    <label for="volume">Volume:</label>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="volume" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="7">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Bootstrap has a class for this called `align-items-end`. I'm just an idiot who read the documentation wrong lol